# How to script bulk nslookups

Tags: linux, bash, shell, whois, nslookup

I have a list of several million domain names and I want to see if they are available or not.

I tried pywhois first but am getting rate limited. As I don't need an authoritative answer, I thought I would just use nslookup. I am having trouble scripting this though.

Basically, what I want to do is, if the domain is registered, echo it. What I'm getting is **grep: find”: No such file or directory** . I think its something easy and I've just been looking at this for too long...

```
#!/bin/bash
START_TIME=$SECONDS
for DOMAIN in `cat ./domains.txt`;
do
    if ! nslookup $DOMAIN | grep -v “can’t find”; then
        echo $DOMAIN
    fi
done
echo ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))
```

Comment: You should not query the DNS for that. A domain name can be registered while not resolving, and this is perfectly normal. `whois` is unfortunately the only generic public interface to get the availability information. Depending on the TLD some registries provide other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have millions to check, you may like to use GNU Parallel to get the job done faster, like this if you want to repeatedly do, say 32 lookups in parallel

```
parallel -j 32 nslookup < domains.txt | grep "^Name"
```

If you want to fiddle with the output of `nslookup`, the easiest way is probably to declare a little function called `lkup()`, tell GNU Parallel about it and then use that, like this

```
#!/bin/bash

lkup() {
  if ! nslookup $1 | grep -v "can't find"; then
     echo $1
  fi
}

# Make lkup() function visible to GNU parallel
export -f lkup

# Check the domains in parallel
parallel -j 32 lkup < domains.txt
```

If the *order* of the lookups is important to you, you can add the `-k` flag to `parallel` to keep the order.

Comment: SO FAST! Thanks Mark!

One quick point: the nslookup is returning reverse domains in some cases (amazonaws for instance...). Do you know a way that I can instead of printing out the matched line from grep, print out the domain that was searched for? Basically I want to just say which domains im searching for exist and which don't.

Comment: I have made a little update to accommodate your comment. If you do any timing with and without `parallel`, maybe you would care to add a comment so I, and other users of SO, can see the effect. Good luck.

Comment: Mark, I am calculating out statistics with parallel right now in order to add them to this thread. Having 1 additional problem with this script and then I think I will be good to go. 

I would like to edit the file domains.txt as it is coming in with awk. Where can I do this and yet maintain the parallel function?

Comment: You can do this `parallel -j 32 lkup < <(awk '{do something}' domains.txt)` as long as you use `bash`.

Comment: If you don't use `bash`, do `awk '{something}' domains.txt | parallel ...`

Comment: Bash is fine. Why the space between the two <'s?

Comment: It is called *process substitution*. It means *"pipe the outout of `awk` into the input of `parallel`"*.... http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: Interesting. Will read. 

Trying that I am getting an error: 

parallel -j 30 lkup < < awk -F"," '{print $2}' $in_file

script.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: You are missing a set of parentheses.

Comment: And if I wanted to add sort -u the results of the AWK?

Comment: Just wrote it as: awk -F "," '{print $2}' $in_file | sort -u | parallel -j 30 lkup

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have curly quotes in your script, which are not the proper way to quote command line elements. As a result, they're being treated as part of a filename. Change to:

```
if ! nslookup $DOMAIN | grep -v "can't find"; then
```